# nomencl with units, nomgroups and longtable

Tags: longtable, nomenclature, units

I use nomencl with nomgroups and nomunit. The only way I achieved to properly align it is given in the picture. It was produced using the methods of the documentation. 
[image]

The file.ist is standard, while tex-file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\makenomenclature
%Pagenumber in nomenclature
\renewcommand{\pagedeclaration}[1]{{\hfill #1}}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{}%
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
 \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{[\parbox{.08\textwidth}{\centering $#1$}]}}

\newlength{\nomentrywidth}
\setlength{\nomentrywidth}{.76\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]
{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}
    {\vspace{2em}\item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
    \hfill \textbf{Abkürzungen} \hfill \hbox{}}
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}
        {\vspace{2em}\item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
        \hfill \textbf{Physikalische Größen} \hfill \hbox{}}
        {%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}
            {\vspace{2em}\item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \hfill \textbf{Regelungstechnik} \hfill \hbox{}}
            {%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{XX}}
            {\vspace{2em}\item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \hfill \textbf{Schriftauszeichnungen} \hfill \hbox{}}
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}

\markright{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\printnomenclature[1.5cm]
\nomenclature[A]{$Re$}{Reynoldszahl\nomunit{-}}%
\nomenclature[R]{$\rho_L$}{Dichte der Luft\nomunit{\frac{kg}{m^3}}}%
\nomenclature[X]{$\eta_L$}{Dynamische Viskosität der Luft\nomunit{\frac{kg}{m \cdot s}}}%
\nomenclature[X]{$\eta_L$}{asdf\nomunit{\frac{kg}{m \cdot s}}}%
\end{document}
%% EOF
```

Unfortunately the page number is before the unit. (Note the `[refpage,intoc]`, which may be removed.)

Can someone give a complete solution either the normal way or with a longtable and explain how I can manipulate the column ordering.

Comment: Please post a complete (small) document that generates this, so people can test their solutions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just edited. Please ignore the umlauts.

Answer (score 2):

You have to "back up":

```
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
 \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{%
   \llap{[\makebox[.08\textwidth]{$#1$}]\hspace{3em}}}}
```

The `\nomentryend` bit will have zero width. Adjust the 3em spacing to suit.